# Python's datetime conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

Here's my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_local_time(time_str):
    """
    takes a string in the format of '27 March at 3:00' which is UTC
    and converts it to local time and AM/PM
    :param time_str:
    """
    offset = datetime.now() - datetime.utcnow()
    time_dt = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%d %b at %H:%M')
    return (time_dt + offset).strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

What I'm having problems with is using a time_str that's only the time and doesn't include the day/month. ie: "02:00"

If I change it to: time_dt = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M') then I get an error about strftime and years before 1900.

So I'm stumped here. What needs done to allow just a time in the input string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `dateutil` package. The `parser.parse()` method is good when your input string changes. It will construct a datetime object with todays date if only time is specified in the string. It will handle various other formats.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

def get_local_time(time_str):
    """
    takes a string in the format of '27 March at 3:00' which is UTC
    and converts it to local time and AM/PM
    :param time_str:
    """
    offset = datetime.now() - datetime.utcnow()
    time_dt = parser.parse(time_str)
    return (time_dt + offset).strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

---

If you are restricted to only datetime package you can do something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_local_time(time_str):
    """
    takes a string in the format of '27 March at 3:00' which is UTC
    and converts it to local time and AM/PM
    :param time_str:
    """
    if len(time_str) <= 5:
        time_str = datetime.now().strftime('%d %B at ') + time_str
    offset = datetime.now() - datetime.utcnow()
    time_dt = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%d %B at %H:%M')
    return (time_dt + offset).strftime('%I:%M %p')

print get_local_time('27 March at 3:00')
print get_local_time('3:00')
```

---

Or you can do it like so:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_local_time(time_str):
    """
    takes a string in the format of '27 March at 3:00' which is UTC
    and converts it to local time and AM/PM
    :param time_str:
    """
    offset = datetime.now() - datetime.utcnow()
    if len(time_str) <= 5:
        time_dt = datetime.combine(datetime.now().date(), datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M').time())
    else:
        time_dt = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%d %B at %H:%M')
    return (time_dt + offset).strftime('%I:%M %p')

print get_local_time('27 March at 3:00')
print get_local_time('3:00')
```

Comment: I'm guessing this would work just fine. But I'm using this in conjunction with another app (Kodi) and since dateutil doesn't seem to be a library included with that, it doesn't work. Still marking it as an answer unless someone has something else.

Comment: @Bahnzo  I'll improve it if you don't want dateutil package. Gimme some time.

Comment: It didn't work, but it was a simple change. The len of the string needed to be 5 instead of 4. so: if len(time_str) <= 5:

Comment: @Bahnzo  Oops I forgot to change 4 to 5 in the 3rd snippet. I did it correctly in the 2nd snippet if you can see.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it in the repl.  It worked for me:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> time = "02:00"
>>> time_dt = datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M')
>>> time_dt
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 0)
>>>
```

If I remember right, a datetime can never store *just* a time, there will always be a dummy date of January 1, 1900.  If you want to store the time without the dummy date, try using the `time` class.  It also has a strftime function, see the docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

You could also try adding a different dummy date to your datetime if it isn't working.

Comment: I'm definitely getting an error. This is being used with an application called "Kodi" which uses python 2.7. so I'm not sure how that's interfering. But you are also right, I can add a dummy day and month and it works fine. Just seems I shouldn't have to.